# Trying to bind a sound to button click on a ListView, app breaks on start

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to trigger an mp3 sound to buttons clicks inside a listView. The app compiles ok and generate the APK. But when starts breaks.

This is the activity:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    MediaPlayer player;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //string data
        String[] myStringArray={
                "ANGUS PREMIUM DELUXE",
                "ANGUS PREMIUM BACON",
                "CUARTO DE LIBRA CON QUESO",
                "DOBLE CUARTO DE LIBRA CON QUESO",
                "McNÍFICA",
                "TRIPLE MAC",
                "BIG MAC",
                "McFIESTA",
                "HAMBURGUESA CON QUESO",
                "HAMBURGUESA"
            };

        //adapter
        ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this,
                // android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                // R.layout.mylayout,
                R.layout.mylayout2,
                R.id.btnAddItem2,
                myStringArray);

        //asociate
        ListView myList =
                (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        assert myList != null;
        myList.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        //sound
        Button btnAddItem = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddItem2);

        btnAddItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //player = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.snd_add_payment);
                //player.start();
           }
        });

    }
}
```

This is the layout that contain the repetitive row:

**mylayout2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAddItem2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="test" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**log with the crash**

```
--------- beginning of crash
06-19 23:53:30.030 2921-2921/moalaiskirulais.com.arrayadapter E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: moalaiskirulais.com.arrayadapter, PID: 2921
                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{moalaiskirulais.com.arrayadapter/moalaiskirulais.com.arrayadapter.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                                    at moalaiskirulais.com.arrayadapter.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:68)
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
06-19 23:53:30.075 1565-2093/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity moalaiskirulais.com.arrayadapter/.MainActivity
```

Comment: I have two quetions. First, do you have any crash log about your problem?  If you had, please update that log. Second, did you set `mMessageClickedHandler` on your view exactly? I can't see method for setting that listener.

Comment: I updated thnx. The mMessageClickedHandler is not breaking the app. The break happen when try to override the onClick(View v)

Comment: In your `activity_main.xml` you don't have the button `btnAddItem2`. Add it there

Comment: @JuanCruzSoler but i need to keep it in mylayout2.xml, is not possible? And second, why the program compiles ok if the element don't exists?

Comment: Use  `<include layout="@layout/mylayout2" />` in your `activity_main.xml`. FindViewById is done at runtime, it does not know if you have the button at compile time

Comment: Your code compiles becauses you have no syntax errors. You have a runtime error because you've not used the API correctly

Comment: It looks like you want one button per row in your ListView. If that is the case, you need a custom ArrayAdapter class and in that class is where you need the OnClickListener. The way you've used it in the Activity is only for one, single button that is in the Activity XML layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have the button `btnAddItem2` in your `activity_main.xml`.
Add this to `activity_main.xml`:

```
<include layout="@layout/mylayout2" />
```

Comment: Thnx now it runs ok. But as @cricket_007 says I need to bind each row in the ListView. Seems I need to read more :] I suposed i could make a massive button binding just referencing the original id (jquery way :D )

Answer (score 1):

I think cricket_007 is right. If you want to control views in each items of list, you must make custom class like this:

**CustomArrayAdapter**

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private ArrayList<String> yourList; // for set data to list.
    private LayoutInflater inflater = null; // for access your views.
    private int layoutResId;

    public CustomArrayAdapter(Context c, int resId, ArrayList<String> list) {
        super(c, resId);
        layoutResId = resId;
        yourList = list;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return yourList.size();
    }

    public void setData(ArrayList<String> list) {
        yourList = list;
    }

    @Override
    public view getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = this.inflater.inflate(layoutResId, null); // inflate your custom layout for list.
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
        }

        holder.button = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnAddItem2);
        holder.button.setText(yourList.get(position).getName());
        holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // make your button event.
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        private Button button;
    }
}
```

Then, try to set this adapter to your listview.

**MainActivity**

```
    // custom adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new CustomArrayAdapter<String>(
            MainActivity.this,
            R.layout.mylayout2,
            myStringArray);

    //asociate
    ListView myList =
            (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    assert myList != null;
    myList.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```